# Mounting a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 with MTP on Linux

Tags: android, debian, tablet, galaxy, mtp

I'm trying to get a Samsung Galaxy Tab2 7.0" connected to a Debian Wheezy box over MTP.  The askubuntu page at https://askubuntu.com/questions/186681/getting-mtp-to-work-with-a-galaxy-tab-2-7-0 details precisely my problem, but none of the suggested remedies work.

To reiterate, I installed mtp-tools and mtpfs.  mtp-detect yields this:

```
libmtp version: 1.1.3

Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung GT P7310/P7510/N7000/I9070/I9100/I9300   Galaxy Tab 7.7/10.1/S2/S3/Nexus/Note/Y.
    Found 1 device(s):
    Samsung: GT P7310/P7510/N7000/I9070/I9100/I9300 Galaxy Tab 7.7/10.1/S2/S3/Nexus/Note/Y  (04e8:6860) @ bus 1, dev 3
Attempting to connect device(s)
PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
LIBMTP PANIC: failed to open session on second attempt
Unable to open raw device 0
OK.
```

I created a /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules file using the values 04e8 for the vendor ID and 6860 for the device ID.  I finished up the aforementioned howto and did this:

```
mkdir foo
mtpfs -o allow_other foo
```

Now doing "ls foo" stalls.  Checking out the directory above foo also stalls.  I cannot get the command lines back without doing "killall -9 mtpfs" (similar to dealing with stale sshfs mounts).  I then see this:

```
ls: cannot access foo: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

Tried https://askubuntu.com/a/88630/27480 and got the same results.

go-mtpfs from https://github.com/hanwen/go-mtpfs also fails:

```
mkdir foo
./go-mtpfs foo
2013/01/07 02:39:33 compiled against libmtp 1.1.3
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung GT P7310/P7510/N7000/I9070/I9100/I9300 Galaxy Tab 7.7/10.1/S2/S3/Nexus/Note/Y.
2013/01/07 02:39:33 found device Samsung: GT P7310/P7510/N7000/I9070/I9100/I9300 Galaxy Tab 7.7/10.1/S2/S3/Nexus/Note/Y (04e8:6860) @ bus 1, dev 3
: 
PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
LIBMTP PANIC: failed to open session on second attempt
2013/01/07 02:41:33 rdev.open failed: open: open returned nil
```

jmptfs from https://github.com/kiorky/jmtpfs.git also fails:

```
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung GT P7310/P7510/N7000/I9070/I9100/I9300 Galaxy Tab 7.7/10.1/S2/S3/Nexus/Note/Y.
PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
LIBMTP PANIC: failed to open session on second attempt
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MtpErrorCantOpenDevice'
  what():  Can't open device
Aborted
```

Comment: I discovered later that upgrading to libmtp-1.1.5 will allow MTP mounts to work.  Still, the mtpfs package misbehaves badly.  It seems that it has a reputation for poor quality.  Jmtpfs works splendidly.  If the author of mtpfs is watching, please consider ripping out the guts of your program and pull in code from jmtpfs.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I was having the same problem.  I had it working on my 32-bit version of 12.04 somehow, but when I reinstalled to update to 64-bits, I had the same problem as you.  For some reason, my old version had 1.1.5, but the new one had 1.1.3 from the standard repository.  I got 1.1.5, and it now works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in a terminal:

```
killall gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
killall gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor
```

After that, reconnect your phone. And use mtp-detect or other libmtp based program. It should work.

This is a workaround I proposed in this ubuntu bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1314556